# Gini coefficients : compare two samples with different sample sizes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, gini

I've two samples representing the distribution of tumor cell clones in two patient. In sample 1 I've about 10,000 clones - each clone has a relative abundance (so the sum of the relative abundance of all clones in one sample is 1). For sample 2 I've about 1,000 clones. The number of clones are different for the two patient because (1) the number of tumor cells are different in both patient and (2) the throughput of the method used for detection of these clones was different (due to technical aspects)..

Can I compare these two samples in terms of Gini coefficient ? I know that the Gini coefficient is sensitive to sample size.

Comment: Do you mean the Gini coefficient that is usually used as a measure of income inequality? (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient ). How are you planning to compare them?

Comment: Yes I meant gini coefficient.